# Javascript Visible Element returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The HTML code that I'm trying to click is

`<button type="submit" class="flatbutton">Send</button>`

```
var i;
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("flatbutton");
    for (i = 0; i < button.length; ++i) {
        if (button[i].type == "submit") {
            console.log(button[i].innertext);
        }
    }
```

For some reason, everything that is returned is undefined. This doesn't make sense, it should be returning "Send".

I'd prefer to only use Javascript and not JQuery

Comment: How can you prefer vanilla JS over jQuery, like have you ever tried jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple typo in your code, `innertext` should be `innerText`

```js
var i;
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("flatbutton");
for (i = 0; i < button.length; ++i) {
  if (button[i].type == "submit") {
    console.log(button[i].innerText);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="flatbutton">Send</button>
```

Comment: you've put a space between `.innerText`

Comment: @Jhecht : thanks , updated !!!

Answer (score 0):

If want to get a single class element better avoid loops. use this. If you have more than one class then use loops.

```
 <button type="submit" class="flatbutton">Send</button>
 var button = document.getElementsByClassName("flatbutton")[0].innerText;
 console.log(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in jQuery like this:

```
$(".flatbutton[type='submit']").each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Or you just make everything more complex by using vanilla JS:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("flatbutton");
for(var i=0;i<btns.length;i++)
{
    var btn=btns[i];
    if(btns.getAttribute("type") == "submit")
    {
        console.log(btn.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

console.log(button[i].innertext);

Use

console.log(button[i].textContent);

Answer (score 0):

You can set a dataattribute on the button and get its value from there.
like this.

```
<button type="submit" class="flatbutton" data-value="send" >Send</button>

var buttonvalue = document.getElementsByClassName("flatbutton").data.value;
```

Why not from JQUERY?
 Or you can try fetching the "send" value by trying .value like this.

```
        var i;
        var button = document.getElementsByClassName("flatbutton");
        for (i = 0; i < button.length; ++i) {
        if (button[i].type == "submit") {
        console.log(button[i].value);
        }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `innertext` to `innerText`. You will get the required result.